# how to change the color of line graph border on hover chartjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am trying to change the color of the border line on the hover.
when the line is hovered then gray the other dataset color
and just show the color of the highlighted dataset border

**1- this when the first dataset 1 is hovering other line graph is gray**

[image]

**2- this is when dataset 2 is hovering other line graph is gray**

[image]

```
import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
} from 'chart.js';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import faker from 'faker';

export const options = {
    responsive: true,
    interaction: {
        mode: 'dataset',
    },

    plugins: {
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Chart.js Line Chart',
        },
    },
};
const labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
console.log(labels.map(() => faker.datatype.number({ min: -1000, max: 1000 })));
export const data = {
    labels,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: [100, -87, 200, 120, 150, 134, 43],
            borderColor: 'rgba(145,147,148,0.7)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'red',
            hoverBorderColor: "red",
            hoverBackgroundColor: "#FC496BFF"
        },
        {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            data: [20, -357, 5, 10, 131, 134, 43],
            borderColor: 'rgb(252,73,107)',
            hoverBorderColor: "blue",
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
        },

        {
            label: 'Dataset 3',
            data: [30, -197, 25, 139, 96, 134, 43],
            borderColor: 'rgba(145,147,148,0.7)',
            hoverBorderColor: "blue",
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.5)',
        },
    ],
};
```